# emacs 23.3b startup over 11 seconds

Tags: emacs23

I've just installed emacs 23.3b (OSX Lion) using brew. The startup takes over 11 seconds (v 22.1 starts instantly). I've blanked out my `.emacs` and tried with various options such as `"-Q"` or `"--no-init-file"` `"--no-site-file"` but the startup time remains 11 seconds.

'`emacs --help`' runs instantly. Also upon loading, I see a message "loading vc-git ... done". Wondering if a lot of files are being loaded. This load time is irrespective of how many times i shut and rerun emacs.

I then installed emacs 23.3b from http://emacsformacosx.com/, that too takes the same time.

How can i speed up the load time, how to figure out where these 11 seconds are going ? (I need to use v23 for using 'evil').

Answer (score 0):

The startup problem persisted with emacs24 also. Seems it was an OSX Lion problem related to /etc/hosts. See [Mac OSX Lion DNS lookup order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order)

The solution to this is have a

```
::1 mydomain.com

entry for every

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com

entry in your hosts file.
```