# PyCharm and Django Shell Networking

Tags: django, networking, connection, port, pycharm

(My Python is installed via Homebrew and correctly refered to by the preferences as my project interpreter)

I have a problem with PyCharms Django Shell. If I start the django shell, it runs the command (ports are changing):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python2.7 -u /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 52135 52136
```

Now, this wont work, it justs states "PyDev Console: starting" and after a while, it stops.

**BUT** when I'm **disabling my Wifi**, it works! Now, what could this be?

(I'm running the latest Mountain Lion OSX, firewall disabled, PyCharm 2.5.2, Django 1.4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related to Mac OS DNS resolution specifics. While trying to resolve this problem with @ruffy, what fixed it was changing the LAN DNS server to Google (`8.8.8.8`).

I've [logged this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7070) in PyCharm tracker so that we can provide a workaround for it in the future updates.

Related topics:

- [Mac OSX Lion DNS lookup order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order)
- [Mac OS X Lion, /etc/hosts Bugs, and DNS Resolution](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I will let this question open and if there is a future workaround/fix I'll close it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, but this was caused because my hostname was 'localhost'. 
Once I changed my hostname to something else (from the sharing section in Preferences) - it worked like a (Py)Charm.

The problem was somewhere in pydev-console, and I don't know why my solution worked - I only guessed it was the problem because originally the console worked, and then it didn't and the only thing had changed was my hostname (due to some fiddling at work)

Comment: this solved the problem for me and was far easier than some of the other solutions around the web.

Comment: Although my computer did't had a hostname assigned in my system preferences (and console didn't worked), assigning anything other than a `localhost` really solves the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

start terminal

> > nano /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py

after line 160 add:

```
    160 def process_exec_queue(interpreter):
  + 161     print 'here'
    162     while 1:
    163     # etcetera
```

save and run shell again, does it show the print message? If it does, move it into the while loop and repeat the process until you've narrowed down the problem

Comment: It's not related to the problem, the console process starts fine and listens on the specified ports, but PyCharm is not able to connect to the process as it uses `localhost` address which cannot resolve properly in some cases.