# Mountain Lion /etc/hosts resolution is slow when offline

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, osx-mountain-lion

Theres a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon) of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order) [discussing](https://serverfault.com/questions/321386/resolving-to-virtual-host-very-slow-on-mac-os-x-lion) slow resolution of /etc/hosts on Mountain Lion. The resolution for my custom host (someserver.dev) is fast when connected to the internet. The moment I go offline the resolution could take up to 30 seconds. Can't seem to find a way to get the resolution to happen quickly without either being online or installing a DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the entries in /etc/hosts need to be on individual lines. For instance, I was also having the problem with this config:

```
 192.168.0.13 my1stmachine.local my2ndmachine.local my3rdmachine.local
```

But after I put each entry on its own line, no slowness anymore:

```
 192.168.0.13 my1stmachine.local
 192.168.0.13 my2ndmachine.local
 192.168.0.13 my3rdmachine.local
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the same thing when I was first messing with it. Didn't work for me, but I've read reports of it working for other people as well.

Comment: You sir, are a life safer!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to install a local DNS server like dnsmasq as seen in [this blog post](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/) by Justin Carmony. It's a bit annoying, but the resolutions come very fast for your local dev servers. You can also do a wildcard entry like this in the dnsmasq.conf file:

```
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

So that anything.dev resolves to your localhost. Hope that helps!