# CSS Caching- Issues with Drupal AND Wordpress

Tags: css, caching

I'm clearly doing something wrong, or there's some setting that I'm overlooking that is causing me serious problems. I cannot get stylesheets to update, either on local installs or server-side installs. I test using multiple browsers. I hard cache them out. I have done everything I can, including totally uninstalling drupal/wordpress... I've gone so far as flushing the DNS on a site I'm working on, cos I was concerned it was the A Name Record (as per a post about this).

This was my Drupal issue: [Drupal 7 Server or Caching Issue? Not updating CSS Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149136/drupal-7-server-or-caching-issue-not-updating-css-changes)

I never came up with a solution for the Drupal issue, and now it's happening locally, on a xampp install on my machine

My problem is that when working either from an FTP through a hosting server, or working on a local Drupal or Wordpress install... I can clear the cache (hard cache) in the browser, I can cache the page. I can timestamp the CSS file. I can query the css file with a random value in the browser. I have tried LITERALLY everything, and I have scoured the web for answers. This is completely ridiculous, but I cannot get the CSS to update. It is a serious problem. I don't know what could be causing it.

I reckon it has to be a setting on my computer? This is just absurd. I'm running Windows 8. I'm about to try doing this on Ubuntu, just to check and see if it's related to something within Windows. I cannot, no matter what, get this to work.

If there is ANYONE on StackOverflow who's fixed this, I would be eternally grateful for help. I'm ripping my hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add a string version at the end of your css file like "style.css?v=1.0.0". Then, change this number at any change you apply to the file.

Answer (score 0):

For **Godaddy server** caching problem you can pass a **nocache=1** paramerter. LIKE:

```
$rand = mt_rand(2,500);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . "style.css?nocache=$rand&", array( 'chld_thm' ) );
```